# Least squares linear classifier in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, least-squares

I'm struggling to understand how to implement a least square linear classifier for my data in matlab. My data has N rows, each row is 10 columns wide. Each row represents a data point with 10 features. There are only two classes, the first N/2 rows of my test data is Class 1 and the rest are Class 2.

All explanations online about least squares make sense, but I'm not able to adapt them to my data, I just need a little bit of conceptual explanation relating to my data and the least square method.

Comment: Perhaps you can regard this as a nonlinear optimization problem, wherein x is the data point, beta is the linear coefficients, and f(beta * x) is the classification result. f(), of course, is a nonlinear function that maps beta * x to 0/1 or -1/1. The error would be Y - f(beta, x), where in Y is the true label. Then you can use the MATLAB function lsqnonlin() to solve this problem.

Answer (score 9):

#### Using least squares for linear classification

The idea of using least squares to create a linear classifier is to define a linear function

```
f(x) = wTx
```

and adjust `w` so that `f(x)` is close to `1` for your data points of one class and close to `-1` for the other class. The adjustment of `w` is done by minimizing for each data point the squared distance between `f(x)` and either `1` or `-1`, depending on its class.

#### Two-dimensional Matlab example

```
% Create a two-cluster data set with 100 points in each cluster
N = 100;
X1 = 0.3*bsxfun(@plus, randn(N, 2), [6 6]);
X2 = 0.6*bsxfun(@plus, randn(N, 2), [-2 -1]);

% Create a 200 by 3 data matrix similar to the one you have
% (see note below why 200 by 3 and not 200 by 2)
X = [[X1; X2] ones(2*N, 1)];

% Create 200 by 1 vector containing 1 for each point in the first cluster
% and -1 for each point in the second cluster
b = [ones(N, 1); -ones(N, 1)]

% Solve least squares problem
z = lsqlin(X, b);

% Plot data points and linear separator found above
y = -z(3)/z(2) - (z(1)/z(2))*x;
hold on;
plot(X(:, 1), X(:, 2), 'bx'); xlim([-3 3]); ylim([-3 3]);
plot(x, y, 'r');
```

[image: Linear separator found by linear least squares]

#### Note on extra column in data matrix

I have added an additional column of ones to the data matrix
in order to allow for a shift of the separator, thus making it a little
more versatile. If you don't do this, you force the separator to pass
through the origin, which will more often than not result in worse
classification results.

Comment: could you also explain a way to evaluate the linear least squares classifier, with the coefficients obtained ? i'm trying to solve a binary classification problem, and when run on test data, the labels I get are real values. How do I classify them to my binary classes ? Most of the resulting labels are positive. Thanks.

Comment: @ggauravr You classify a test point `x` by the sign of `w^T x`, i.e. if `w^T x > 0` the point is in the first class, otherwise if `w^T x < 0` it is in the second class.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. Your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @3lectrologos, how does the extra column impact the linear separator found? When I set the extra column values to 0 instead of 1 I get a better solution. And even more so when half of the extra column values are -1 and the other 0.

Comment: The extra column adds an extra degree of freedom, which corresponds to allowing the linear separator to not pass through (0, 0). If you add a column different than all ones, you essentially add another feature to your data set. (Of course, if you have this kind of information, you can add it to your data matrix and possibly improve the result.)

Comment: @3lectrologos, if you have a training set, can you put the correct class values in the third column? I appreciate the help.

Comment: No, the correct class values are put in a separate vector (called `b` in the above code snippet) to train the classifier.

Comment: @3lectrologos, one last question. Why does `a = -z(3)/z(2)` and `b =  - (z(1)/z(2))` in the final linear equation? `lsqlin` returns a vector with `n` elements, the same number of variables/columns in the `C` matrix. So how would we construct the linear equation with four, five, etc. variables?

Comment: That is only used to visualize the linear separator in two dimensions, and results from solving `w^T x = 0`. For an arbitrary number of dimensions you would just use `sign(w^T x)` to classify a new point `x` into one of the two classes.